# remove timestamp column from log file without affecting actual logs in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have log files with time stamps, I want to remove those timestamps and just keep the logs as it is.
File content is as follows.

```
$ cat test 
04-13 04:33:11.341: abc : xyz
04-13 04:33:11.342: aaa------ : bbbb
04-13 04:33:11.342: sometext sometext
```

I tried to remove it using awk with below command.

```
$ cat test | awk -F": " '{$1=""; print}'
 abc  xyz
 aaa------  bbbb
 sometext sometext
```

But as you see it removes `:` from actual logs as well ?
Is awk wrong choice for this, I can't use cut as I am using two character long delimiter.

Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a more specifying delimiter

```
$ awk -F "[0-9]: " '{$1=""; print}' test
 abc : xyz
 aaa------ : bbbb
 sometext sometext
```

That means: The delimiter is the sequence `digit`, `:`, `space`.

`awk` removes the field separator (`FS`) from the input file and replaces them by the output field separator (`OFS`). That is normally invisible to the user if he uses the default values. You may set `OFS=FS` to keep the field separator in the output:

```
$ awk -F ": " 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}{$1=""; print}' test
: abc : xyz
: aaa------ : bbbb
: sometext sometext
```

Answer (score 2):

If that is the only/exact structure of your data then `cut`. otherwise, yeah, `awk` or `sed` and friends.

```
cut -d ' ' -f3- file.txt
```

Output

```
abc : xyz
aaa------ : bbbb
sometext sometext
```